# how can fetch all object of columns in php?

Tags: php

I take all columns of table and want fetch object of each this columns.

This is my code so far but not work:

```
public function TakeAll($name){

   $sql = 'SELECT * FROM Rap WHERE RapperName = :name';
   $query = $this -> conn -> prepare($sql);
   $query -> execute(array(':name' => $name));

    $row_count = $query -> fetchColumn();

  for($i = 0; $i <= $row_count; $i++){

     $data = $query -> fetchObject();

        $user["rapper"] = $data -> RapperName;
        $user["musicpath"] = $data -> MusicPath;
        $user["musicname"] = $data -> MusicName;
         return $user;

   }
}
```

With this way just fetch one object but I have 3 object with that name in my table and I want fetch all that three.

> i set `$data = $query -> fetchObject($i);` but then not show even that one object also...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to stop overriding the array again and again:-**

```
public function TakeAll($name){

   $sql = 'SELECT * FROM Rap WHERE RapperName = :name';
   $query = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
   $query->execute(array(':name' => $name));

   $row_count = $query->fetchColumn();
   $user = array(); // take array
   $i = 0; // an increment variable
   while($data = $query->fetchObject()){

      $user[$i]["rapper"] = $data->RapperName;
      $user[$i]["musicpath"] = $data->MusicPath;
      $user[$i]["musicname"] = $data->MusicName;
      $i++;
      // assign values to array with indexes of 0,1,2.....
   }
   return $user; // return final multi-dimensional array
}
```

Comment: i take this in another class like this :    $all = $db -> TakeAll($name);
      
       $response["user"] = $all;
      return json_encode($response); is this correct ?

Comment: @user7415865  i didn't get you

Comment: dude every thing is fine but i don't know why that loop just return all data -1 . it mean if i had 4 object it return 3object ...for example i have 4column with 1name but it just return 3first column or if i had 8column with 1name it return 7of theme ... always not return the last row of we insert in data base

Comment: it will depend on query output. Also indexes start from 0, so don't confuse. if you have 4 then it will show 0,1,2,3

Comment: yes i know it and in out put i started from 0 but i have 4 column in table and i start from 0,1,2 take this three objects but for 3 get null

Comment: @user7415865  please ask a new question with input details and database value pictures and what problem you are facing . and put this link as a reference. Thanks

Comment: can you change loop while depend to row count ? i give you up vote your answer

Comment: while is doing same